# testing angular 2 services with jasmine using async promises

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, jasmine, pouchdb

so, i'm having some trouble testing my angular 2 service. my tests are marked as passing but i'm getting this error in my console:

> context.js:243 Unhandled Promise rejection: 'expect' was used when
>   there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test
>   timed out ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:
>   'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be
>   because an asynchronous test timed out

my service uses PouchDB and returns a promise.

here's my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from './project';
declare var PouchDB:any;

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

  db: any;

  constructor() {
    if(navigator.vendor && navigator.vendor.indexOf('Apple') > -1){
      this.db = new PouchDB('projects', {adapter: 'fruitdown'});
    }else{
      this.db = new PouchDB('projects');
    }   
  }

  saveProject(project:Project): Promise<any>{
    return this.db.put(project);
  }

  getProjects(limit:number,skip:number): Promise<any> {
    return this.db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true,
      attachments: false,
      descending: true,
      limit: limit,
      skip: skip
    });
  }

}
```

here's my spec

```
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Project, ProjectService } from './index';

describe('ProjectService', () => {

  let project: Project;
  let service: ProjectService;

  let createFakeProject = function() {
    let project = new Project;
    project._id = 'iwhxu27i';
    project.name = 'foo bar';
    project.email = 'foo@b.ar';
    return project;
  }


  beforeEach(() => {
    const injector = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ProjectService]
    });

    service = injector.get(ProjectService);
    project = createFakeProject();

  });

  it('should be able to CREATE a new project (async)',
    async( (done) => {
    service.saveProject(project).then( 
      response => {
        expect(response).toEqual(project);
        done();
      } );

  }));

});
```

...okay, so i've been fiddling with this for a while. i might need to be using fakeAsync and tick()?? fakeAsync doesn't feel right, tho. it does seem like i should call done() in a .finally() block but .finally() is not a method. i'm new to testing Promises with Jasmine, so maybe i'm missing something obvious? if you know any code (or example code) out there that uses angular2, jasmine, and promises; that would be helpful.

i don't want to mock PouchDB and return my own stubbed Promise.

this test should fail since response != project; it does not but i get an error in my console. help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise returned by `service.saveProject(project).then(` is not awaited, either remove the `async` from the method, and return this promise from the test, or await the promise result in the test.

```
it('should be able to CREATE a new project (async)',
    async (done) => {
      let response = await service.saveProject(project)
      expect(response).toEqual(project);
  });
```